# TV episode, possibly "Twilight Zone" about a man who becomes a card dealer by putting on special shoes

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification, the-twilight-zone

Looking for a TV episode, I'm thinking *Twilight Zone*.

A man tries on dress shoes he's not supposed to. Every time he puts them on he becomes a card dealer and he falls in love with the night life. His wife is pregnant. I believe he works at a shoe store or cleaners.

Comment: I only remember 2 episodes of Twilight Zone about shoes - What You Need and Dead Man's Shoes. Neither of those fit the description. The first is about an arrogant guy and a peddler who can give anyone what they need. The shoes only appear at the end. And the second is about a homeless guy who becomes possessed by the wearer of the shoes he finds.

Comment: @Tical Benjamin - Hi, welcome to the site. Was this episode in black & white or in colour? Also, are you certain that the man became a card dealer specifically? Was he actually shown doing that in the episode?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a bit like the *Tales from the Darkside* episode, "[The Social Climber](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0716999/)".

From the [Headhunter's Horror House Wiki](https://headhuntershorrorhouse.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_from_the_Darkside:_The_Social_Climber):

> "The Social Climber" is the nineteenth episode of season three of the horror anthology television series *Tales from the Darkside* and the sixty-seventh episode of the series overall. It was directed by Armand Mastroianni with a teleplay written by Ellen Sandhaus. It first aired in syndication on Sunday, March 8th, 1987.

From a [review](https://midnitereviews.com/2018/05/tales-from-the-darkside-episode-66-the-social-climber/):

> While working for a shoemaker named Anthony (Albert Hague), Rob (Robert Romanus)—a dreamer with high aspirations—discovers that he can experience the lives of other people by wearing their shoes. Against the warnings of his boss, Rob continues to wear the shoes of Anthony’s customers—with a ghastly outcome.

As noted above, the main character, Rob, works for a shoemaker named Anthony, an elderly man. Anthony seems to be able to imbue some type of magic into the shoes he makes which allows the wearer to experience the lifestyle of whoever the shoes were made for. He keeps these shoes in a back room though, and doesn't tell Rob about them.

One night while closing up the store alone, Rob sees a pair of these shoes and tries them on. Then he steps in front of a mirror to see how they look, and sees that the rest of his clothes have changed into a tuxedo. The following day, he tells a female customer that he attended a celebrity bash at the Waldorf Astoria that night, and had drinks with the major.

Later, he tries on a different pair of shoes, and when he looks in the mirror he sees that the rest of his clothes have changed again. The following day, he tells the same customer he spoke to before that he spent the night playing roulette and craps at a club.

Anthony figures out what's going on, and tells Rob not to wear these pairs of shoes anymore, and that he should be grateful for the life he already has. For example, Rob has a sweet and loving girlfriend that he's due to marry in a couple of months. Rob agrees, and says he won't wear the shoes anymore.

I won't spoil how the episode ends, as it doesn't reveal anything relevant to the description. Note that we don't actually see any of Rob's nightly excursions though; the entire episode is set within the shoe shop, and we're only told of events that occurred off-screen. Also, Rob's girlfriend, who we see visit the store a couple of times, isn't said or shown to be pregnant.